# How to include images in a jekyll project hosted on github?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-flavored-markdown

I'm building a blog using jekyll and hosting it on github with gh-pages. The root of my project can be see seen below:

```
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── _config.yml
├── _img
│   ├── 2016-09-09\ 14.48.20.png
│   └── 2016-09-09\ 15.25.09.png
.
.
.
├── _posts
│   ├── 2016-09-08-seven-weeks-before-applying-to-devops-job.markdown
│   └── 2016-09-09-an-hour-with-ansible.md
.
.
.
├── _site
│   ├── 2016
│   │   └── 09
│   │       ├── 08
│   │       │   └── seven-weeks-before-applying-to-devops-job.html
│   │       └── 09
│   │           └── an-hour-with-ansible.html
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── about
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── css
│   │   └── main.css
│   ├── feed.xml
│   └── index.html
├── about.md
├── css
│   └── main.scss
├── feed.xml
└── index.html
```

The documentation gives the following example:

> Because of Jekyll’s flexibility, there are many solutions to how to do this. One common solution is to create a folder in the root of the project directory called something like `assets` or `downloads`, into which any images, downloads or other resources are placed. Then, from within any post, they can be linked to using the site’s root as the path for the asset to include. Again, this will depend on the way your site’s (sub)domain and path are configured, but here are some examples (in Markdown) of how you could do this using the `site.url` variable in a post.

Including an image asset in a post:

```
... which is shown in the screenshot below:
![My helpful screenshot]({{ site.url }}/assets/screenshot.jpg)
```

I've tried several different ways but non are working once I push `gh-pages` up:

```
![]({{ site.github.url }}/_img/2016-09-09 14.48.20.png)

![]({{ site.url }}/_img/2016-09-09 15.25.09.png)
```

I've also tried "keeping" the `_img` directory by putting the following in my `_config.yaml`

```
# Build settings
markdown: kramdown

keep_files: ["_img"]
```

But this also is not working. So how do I include images in a jeykll project hosted on github?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every folder beginning with an underscore won't be copied to the build destination. The most common way is to store images is to add them to a `assets/img` folder.
If you want to use `_img` you have to add to your `_config.yml`:

```
include:
  - "_img"
```

Answer (score -2):

- Create a folder for your images, you can name it according to your wish (mine is "images")
- Find the image address of that image that you want to include in your post
  (You can do that by going to your folder image and right click on your image, then copy image address)
- Now you use that address in your post without any problem.