# images not showing in github pages

Tags: image, github, markdown, jekyll

I have github pages everything is working just fine except for the images stuff. I've tried everything to make the image show up on my GitHub pages site but nothing is working

here is the code:

```
<figure>
  <img src="./img/dutchboys_plot.jpg">
  <figcaption>Hasil plotting dataset menggunakan ggplot2</figcaption>
</figure>
```

It should be looks like this:

[image]

but this is how my github pages looks like:

[image: my github pages]

This is the repo of my github pages: https://github.com/oktavianuu/oktavianuu.github.io

I will be very grateful if there is anyone who can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Try `![Img alt text](./img/dutchboys_plot.jpg)` however, it should be a full url on GitHub.

Comment: okay I'll try and will give you update.

Comment: @imaCoden, Thanks but still, the image not showing :(

Comment: This worked for me: `![Hasil plotting dataset menggunakan ggplot2](https://github.com/oktavianuu/oktavianuu.github.io/blob/b862ac98930e9ddd7af1555b799030ebf1c5c320/assets/img/dutchboys_plot.jpg "Hasil plotting dataset menggunakan ggplot2")`

Comment: I have tried this: ```![Hasil plotting dataset menggunakan ggplot2](https://github.com/oktavianuu/oktavianuu.github.io/blob/main/_posts/kurva-pertumbuhan-gamlss/img/dutchboys_plot.jpg "```Hasil plotting dataset menggunakan ggplot2")
but still not working!

thanks a lot btw.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include images in a jekyll project hosted on github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428263/how-to-include-images-in-a-jekyll-project-hosted-on-github)