# .png images not appearing in github page site

Tags: image, jekyll, github-pages

I built my site using jekyll and have been looking at stackoverflow to try and resolve my issue (images rendering in .md file used to generate post, but post itself does not show images).

- [my github.io blog post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtFhB.png)
- [root of my website project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFxkI.png)
- [when in _posts/2023/10/23/Delivery-Time-Prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouK90.png)

Using this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428263/how-to-include-images-in-a-jekyll-project-hosted-on-github),

I added `/assets` and put a test image in there. Then I referred to it in my [__posts/post.md file](https://github.com/mindyng/mindyng.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2023-10-23-Delivery-Time-Prediction.md)  and it rendered there. However, when I went to click on the [post](https://mindyng.github.io/blog/2023/10/23/Delivery-Time-Prediction), the picture did not appear. I also tried adding `include: - "_posts"` to my _config.yml file and that did not work either.

This is the usual markdown code to render images in .md files:

`![nominal_distribution](nom_dist.png)`

This is the code in my config file:

```
markdown: kramdown
permalink: /blog/:year/:month/:day/:title
include: - "_posts"
```

Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put images in `/assets/images/`, then you can access them from any post file, like

```
![image](/assets/images/image.png)
```

Comment: thanks a bunch! my .png files got moved to /assets/images and have now rendered in my GitHub website with the above path you provided. :)

Comment: Glad it helped! You can accept my answer then :)